# Is it possible to convert a 3D pointcloud into a 3D mesh with rgl (or any other R package)?

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I am trying to find a way to easily convert pointclouds (describing complex surfaces) into a mesh object with rgl. I know there are meshing softwares out there, but does anyone know if it can be done in R?
Thanks!

EDIT: an example with a dinosaur

```
library(datasauRus)
library(dplyr)
library(rgl)
dino <- datasauRus::datasaurus_dozen %>%
  filter(dataset == "dino") %>%
  select(-dataset)
dino <- rbind(dino, dino)
dino$z <- c(rep(0,142), rep(1,142))

plot3d(dino)

dino_mesh <- rgl::as.mesh3d(
  x = dino$x, y = dino$y, z = dino$z)

plot3d(dino_mesh)

# --> This conversion to a 3D mesh did not work well
```

[dino points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVhkv.png)
[meshed dino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSCmH.png)

Comment: It depends on the pointcloud.  `?rgl::as.mesh3d.ashape3d` shows one possibility.  If you want more help, you're going to have to tell us more about what your data looks like, ideally posting some data like it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added an example with a dummy dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The demo points don't define a 3D surface: they're just a line drawing in 2D.  But you can still make a mesh out of it by joining the corresponding points, e.g.

```
index <- rep(c(1, 143, 144, 1, 144, 2), 141) + rep(0:140, each=6)
mesh <- mesh3d(dino, triangles = index)
open3d()
shade3d(mesh, col = "gray")
aspect3d(1, 1, 0.2)
```

which produces this:

[image: screenshot]

Filling in the sides would be harder, because there's no indication in the dataset what should be closed in.